# Relative import of package in script: Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following:

```
Top/
--- top.py
--- inside/
    --- __init.py__
    --- inside.py
```

I want to include inside.py(package) into top.py(script).

If i write : `from inside import inside` it works on the console i.e if I do python3 top.py but this gives error in PyCharm. If however, I do : `from .inside import inside` it then does not give error in PyCharm also. [Python doc on import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html): Submodules section provides that doing this is allowed.

But I read from multiple posts that relative imports are not allowed in python3 and that we need to use sys.path.

Please explain. Also, I do understand there have been multiple posts on the topic , but i believe most of them are about importing inside modules.

Comment: "relative imports are not allowed in python3" [citation needed]

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Looking for the exact question but most of the posts claim to set path in PYTHONPATH or use absolute path  using sys.path